# I want to combine the values ​of objects in different arrays by sorting them one side

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, frontend

I want to concatenate the values ​​of objects in different arrays to one side.
I tried to output the data value received in json to console.log.

I want to put the values ​​in the Ingredient List into the List array.

```
console.log(detail);

 {
       List: [
        {
          id: 120,
          content: "stack-overflow",
          functionalList: [
            {
                id: 832,
            },
          ],
        },
         {
          id: 230,
          content: "heap-overflow",
          functionalList: [
            {
                id: 24,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],

      ListValue: [
        {
          IngredientList: [
            {
                id: 1,
                value: 43
            },
             {
                id: 23,
                value: 23
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
```

I want to put ListValue -> IngredientList value values ​​into List array object.
How can I do it this way? I've been trying all day, but it's hard for me.

```
{
     List: [
      {
        id: 120,
        content: "stack-overflow",
        value: 43
        functionalList: [
          {
              id: 832,
              functionalId: 37
          },
        ],
      },
       {
        id: 230,
        content: "heap-overflow",
        value: 23
        functionalList: [
          {
              id: 24,
              functionalId: 12
          },
        ],
      },
    ],

    ListValue: [
      {
        IngredientList: [
          {
              id: 1,
              value: 43
          },
           {
              id: 23,
              value: 23
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in a mutable approach, even if you have multiple objects inside ListValue:

```
data.List = [
  ...data.List,
  ...data.ListValue.reduce((arr, el) => {
    arr.push(...el.IngredientList);
    return arr;
  }, []),
];
```

Comment: I am getting the error utils.js:324 Uncaught TypeError: data.List is not iterable.

Comment: I called *data" the name of your json object.

Comment: Should I group data into objects?
data is set to useState.

Comment: Manipulate it before setting to useState:
e.g.: `res.json().then( data => { const list = [
  ...data.List,
  ...data.ListValue.reduce((arr, el) => {
    arr.push(...el.IngredientList);
    return arr;
  }, []),
]; 
setState(list)}`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which value of the `IngredientList` should go in which item of `List`. Supposing you always want to pair the first value with the first item, the second with the second, and so on...

```js
const obj = {
  List: [
    {
      id: 120,
      content: "stack-overflow",
      functionalList: [
        {
          id: 832,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 230,
      content: "heap-overflow",
      functionalList: [
        {
          id: 24,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],

  ListValue: [
    {
      IngredientList: [
        {
          id: 1,
          value: 43,
        },
        {
          id: 23,
          value: 23,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const ingridientsValue = obj.ListValue[0].IngredientList.map(el => el.value); // [43, 23]

for (const item of obj.List) item.value = ingridientsValue.shift();

console.log(obj.List);
```

Comment: TypeError: obj.List is not iterable error occurs in the for statement obj.List . So I modified it to Object.entries(obj.List),
A TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object error occurs.

Comment: I set it as Object.entries(obj.List || {}) in the for statement, but an undefined value comes out.

Comment: I tried excluding Object.entries
I'm getting an Uncaught TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) error.

Comment: Should I group data into objects?
data is set to useState.

Comment: In your code `List` belongs to an unnamed object. Here I gave a name to this object: I called it `obj` (see first line `const obj = {`). You can't loop over `obj.List` if in your code the variable `obj` doesn't exist. If this outer object is a state, use the name of the state to refer to it, and change `obj.List` to `stateName.List`.

Answer (score 0):

**I have solved this. Check it out here:** https://jsfiddle.net/bowtiekreative/o5rhy7c1/1/

First your JSON needs to be validated.
Remove the  ")" and the extra ","

**Instructions**

1. Create an empty array called arr.
2. Loop through the ListValue array.
3. For each item in the ListValue array, loop through the IngredientList array.
4. For each item in the IngredientList array, push the value property into the arr array.
5. Log the arr array to the console.

**Example:**

```
    var json = {
   "List":[
      {
         "id":120,
         "content":"stack-overflow",
         "functionalList":[
            {
               "id":832
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":230,
         "content":"heap-overflow",
         "functionalList":[
            {
               "id":24
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "ListValue":[
      {
         "IngredientList":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "value":43
            },
            {
               "id":23,
               "value":23
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
};

var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.ListValue.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < json.ListValue[i].IngredientList.length; j++) {
        arr.push(json.ListValue[i].IngredientList[j].value);
    }
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: @minsu123 have you tried?

Comment: It comes out as an empty array value.

Comment: Should I group data into objects?
data is set to useState.

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: @minsu123 do you want to do a zoom call?

Comment: Receive asynchronous data from react Query, operate the data in the onSuccess part, put it in dataList, and then useState (data, setData)

I put it in setData(dataList).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243921/discussion-between-minsu123-and-ryan-perez).